# Why would Airflow Scheduler only work as a non-daemon process but fail as a daemon process?

Tags: python, airflow, daemon, airflow-scheduler

I have set up airflow on an Ubuntu server. I started the webserver just fine as a daemon process. I can start the scheduler using

```
airflow scheduler
```

and it works fine and the dags run. I then stop it and remove all the airflow-scheduler files in $AIRFLOW_HOME (airflow-scheduler.err, airflow-scheduler.log, airflow-scheduler.out)

I then try to start it as a daemon process using

```
airflow scheduler -D
```

It appears to start okay without error. However when I got to the webserver it says:

"The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 2 minutes ago.

The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled."

When I look in airflow-scheduler.err I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emauser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 503, in <lambda>
  File "/home/emauser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 702, in _finalize_fairy
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1337, in error
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1444, in _log
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1454, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1516, in callHandlers
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 865, in handle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1071, in emit
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

Any idea why I'm getting an error on the built-in open function from the logging module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before restarting your scheduler in daemon mode, make sure no other scheduler process are running.
`ps aux | grep airflow-scheduler`

If there are any , kill them and then start your scheduler as a daemon .